# socketchannel.write has a limit?

Tags: java, tcp, server, nio

I'm writing a nio server,process some http request

and I want to use SocketChannel 's method `write(ByteBuffer[] srcs)`,

code like this

```
@Override
public void send(ByteBuffer[] arr) throws IOException {
    long writeBytes=channel.write(arr);
    log.debug("writeBytes "+writeBytes);
}
```

but if `arr` is too big ,such as 93k ,it can only write

```
DEBUG : 2017-08-25 15:03:41 > writeBytes16384
```

And in the brower , of course it's not complete,only a part of it

if I split it ,such as

```
@Override
public void send(byte[] bytes, int index, int length) throws IOException {
    ByteBuffer buffer=ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
    try {
        buffer.put(bytes,index,length);
    }catch (BufferOverflowException e){
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    buffer.flip();
    channel.write(buffer);
}
```

and use `Thread.sleep(2)` after every method,and send 93 times in loop,it's ok,but I don't think it is a good way

16384 is 16k,I realy think some buffer is 16k,but I didn't found which buffer is

I saw `channel.socket().getSendBufferSize();` is 8192

I try to `channel.socket().setSendBufferSize(4*1024*1024);`

but it didn't work

How can I success to transfer a big data (more than 16k) to brower one time and not sleep or wait

Comment: That's pretty much the whole idea when using non-blocking IO. I think you need to read a good tutorial, because currently you're way off. Or switch to blocking IO.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Keyaman

you are right ,I should read some tutorials

I fix it,it works well

```
while(arr[arr.length-1].hasRemaining()){
        long writeBytes=channel.write(arr);
        log.debug("writeBytes "+writeBytes);
    }
```

but I still don't it is a good way

it log just like this

```
    DEBUG : 2017-08-25 16:26:56 > writeBytes 16384
    DEBUG : 2017-08-25 16:26:56 > writeBytes 0
    DEBUG : 2017-08-25 16:26:56 > writeBytes 0
    DEBUG : 2017-08-25 16:26:56 > writeBytes 0
    ...
    DEBUG : 2017-08-25 16:26:56 > writeBytes 16384
    DEBUG : 2017-08-25 16:26:56 > writeBytes 0
    DEBUG : 2017-08-25 16:26:56 > writeBytes 0
    DEBUG : 2017-08-25 16:26:56 > writeBytes 0
    ...
    DEBUG : 2017-08-25 16:26:56 > writeBytes 0
    DEBUG : 2017-08-25 16:26:56 > writeBytes 12922
```

there should be a buffer is 16k,when it's full ,it flush

what is it,and can I set it?

Comment: No you shouldn't. You should read the tutorials, and about a hundred answers here on the same topic. When `write()` returns zero, you should select on OP_WRITE to tell you when the channel is writable, instead of mindlessly spinning like this.